# BCD at Sharepoint how to put paging on ASP Calendar

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, asp-classic, calendar, caml

I have got a Question. How to put a Paging by a Caml Queries ,and add the pagging to the ASP Calendar. I must take data from External List which are situated on CRM Microsoft Dynamics and put back from CRM as external lists. I must put all together to ASP calendar. Please help